# How to match any quoted strings containing Cyrillic symbols

Tags: ruby, regex

Need parse a lot of text files and replace any quoted strings containing cyrillic symbols. They are may contains new lines, non-alphabetic characters and special symbols (for example '$' or escaped quote).
Can anyone help with regex?

From comments:

for example php code

```
function hello($word) {
    $word2 = "ха-ха!";
    echo "Привет, $word $word2\n"; 
}
hello('Мир');
```

I need match "ха-ха!", "Привет, $word $word2\n" and 'Мир'

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you included an example of the data you are trying to parse.

Comment: for example php code
`function hello($word)
{
    $word2 = "ха-ха!";
    echo "Привет, $word $word2\n";
}

hello('Мир');`
I need match "ха-ха!", "Привет, $word $word2\n" and 'Мир'

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
str = 'The cat is under the "таблица"'
regex = /"\p{Cyrillic}+.*?\.?"/ui

str.match(regex){|s| do_stuff_with_each_matching s} 

# or...

str.gsub!(regex){|s| method_that_translates_russian s}
```

Check it out on live at http://rubular.com/r/0Mwbfinjvp.
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

`".*[^a-zA-Z\d]+.*"` matches any **quoted** character sequence containing **at least one non-alphanumeric character**.

i.e. it matches `"aa$bb"` and `"a1$b1"`

It doesn't match `"aabb"` or `a$b`.

Hope that this is what you want (Add required escaping).

Comment: it's no working for new lines.
And if I add `//m` for regex it's match all file